# Is it possible to get the country code of a user from Facebook's Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, country-codes

When i tried to get the current location of a user via FQL, Graph API returned something like this;

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "current_location": {
        "city": "Izmir",
        "state": "Izmir",
        "country": "Turkey",
        "zip": "",
        "id": 107968765903327,
        "name": "İzmir, Turkey"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Using the Graph ID above, i checked the location information from https://graph.facebook.com/107968765903327 and this time i get more data about the city;

```
{
   "id": "107968765903327",
   "name": "\u0130zmir, Turkey",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/\u0025C4\u0025B0zmir-Turkey/107968765903327",
   "likes": 178460,
   "category": "City",
   "is_published": true,
   "is_community_page": true,
   "description": "\u003Cp>\u003Cb>Izmir\u003C/b> is a large ...",
   "location": {
      "latitude": 38.4072,
      "longitude": 27.1503
   },
   "checkins": 9059,
   "talking_about_count": 238710
}
```

But, as you see, there is no chance for the country code with these options. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The above call is for a page, not a user.
With a user, you get the locale, which is the language and country code. It's not a strict country code. Check this out:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/

Comment: Country codes are relatively stable, so a one-to-one mapping between the country name and code should suffice. For instance, scraping the table found here should be a good start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reverse geocode could help 
see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Thanks Luca, i didn't think to get the country code from another source. This will solve the problem...